# Signing a csr with a private key using openssl

Tags: openssl

I am trying to sign a CSR provided by an end-user entity and I have the private key and certificate of the intermediate CA. Every example I come across online uses a .cnf file that is passed as an argument. Is there a way by which I can sign a CSR without having to use a .cnf file in the command(by only using the cert and key of the intermediate CA)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority)

Comment: @jww I've already referred to the pointed question before posting and dont think this one is a duplicate of that one. I did not want to use any configuration file and that was my main concern. The accepted and only  answer in the pointed post uses a configuration file which was what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: You can't avoid a CONF file *if* you want a well formed signing request or self signed certificate. That's because the CONF file is the *only* way to specify *Subject Alternate Names*.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself. You can use the -CA and -CAkey options to pass the information and have the cert signed.

For example, you would do:

```
openssl x509 -req -in someCSR.pem -CA <signerCert>.pem -CAkey <signerKey>.pem -CAcreateserial -out <signedCert>.pem.
```

Comment: This uses the default CONF file. If you want to convince yourself, open the file `openssl.cnf`, and delete the ***`[req]`***, ***`[v3_req]`*** sections.